# Is it possible to load a ui view with parameter when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angular-ui-router

Can I navigate user to the first ui-sref link present in jsp on jsp body load with a request parameter?

I am sharing my code.

**test.jsp**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-iem">
                <a>${clientId}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" ui-sref="dashboard({clientID: ${clientId}})">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" ui-sref="clientDetail({clientID: ${clientId}})">Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**AngularApp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/:clientID',
        resolve: {
            getList1: [ 'getService', '$stateParams', function(getService, $stateParams) {
                return getService.getData('/mybackend/url1?clientId=' + $stateParams.clientID);
            } ]
        },
        templateUrl: '/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
    })
    .state('clientDetail', {    
        url: '/clientDetail/:clientID',
        resolve: {
            user: [ 'getService', '$stateParams', function(getService,$stateParams) {
                return getService.getData('/mybackend/url2?clientId=' + $stateParams.clientID);
            } ]
        },
        templateUrl: '/myProfile.html',
                controller : 'myProfileCtrl',
    })
```

When I log in successfully, then I receive my clientID as request parameter from backend. But user is not routed to dashboard unless I click on "Dashboard".

I also tried using otherwise like this -

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    var state = $injector.get('$state');
    state.go("dashboard", $location.search());
    return $location.path();
});
```

But it is showing that the stateParams passed is undefined.

I am quite sure I am missing some basic concept but I am unable to find any clue in google. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass state parameter like this :

The URL can take several different options and we can set the basic parameters in the url like in ngRoute:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('inbox', {
    url: '/inbox/:inboxId',
    template: '<h1>Welcome to your inbox</h1>',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                 $scope.inboxId = $stateParams.inboxId;
                }
 });
```

**OR in you case :**

The app captures : clientId as the second component in the URL. For instance, **if the user transitions to /mybackend/1**, $stateParams.clientId becomes 1 (as $stateParams will be {clientId: 1}).

**We can also use a different syntax if you prefer:**

```
url: '/mybackend/{clientId}'
```

Comment: Yes this will work properly if I click on dashboard. Basically I need to route to dashboard with clientID as parameter without any click when the test.jsp is loading.

Comment: So you can use route state change events one of from my given answer, let me to update my answer, follow the link which i gonna to put.

Comment: I checked your link. My issue is the parameter clientID is passed as undefined when I try to load using $urlRouterProvider. Other than that, it is working fine.

Comment: I am sorry but it's still not working. It seems like I cannot pass the parameter clientID from my .jsp to $stateProvider, it wont route to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. Though it is not ideal solution, but it's working as of now. I have triggered a click event on "dashboard" tab as soon as the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navItem1").trigger('click');
})
```